# Node.js - how to implement api/:product_url

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest

I am new to node.js and I am using Yeoman to fetch a product details from the list of products. I am getting data from a triple store database and converting to json. The only unique ID is in the form of URL with an hash encoded at last.

In `demo.controller.js`:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.json(response);
}
```

In `index.js`:

```
var controller = require('./demo.controller');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', controller.index);
module.exports = router;
```

Here, response output is the following json structure for `URL/api/product_list`:

```
[{
    "url":"http://example.com/demo/32b9jkd902n2"
    "product":"stack",
    "name":"test",
    "price":"233"
}, {
    "url":"http://example.com/demo/5nf9djdkdks0"
    "product":"flow",
    "name":"dev",
    "price":"433"
}]
```

Now, I want to get details of each product. something like `URL/api/product_list/:product_url` ?

Basically, when I access url with `product_url` from the list of products, I should be able to get the product details.

Can someone help me in implementing the URL with `/api/product_list/:product_url` with an output of single product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as there is no other unique identifier besides the URL you could to one of the following:

- Parse unique ID from the url to `/api/product_list` as `id` to the output and use that - `/api/product_list/:id`
- Generate a hash (md5, sha1) of the whole url to the output as `id` and use that as an unique id.

Note: never used Yeoman before, so I don't know if you have some limitations from there.

I think `/api/product_list/:url` will not fly, and if it does, it sure will look ugly.